# Apache redirecting https://host:port/folder to http://host:port/folder/

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, https

I have a apache server using two SSL domains (no SNI support) in different ports, kinda like this:

- https://host1.tld:443 (default)
- https://host2.tld:444 (non-standard)

I have a Rewrite rule to redirect http://host2.tld:80 to :444 (and the same to host1). Then there is the problem:

I have a folder "folder" on host2 root. If I try to access http://host2.tld/folder/, everything is ok and I end up in https://host2.tld:444/folder/ as expected. Now, if I type http://host2.tld/folder, apache redirect me to http://host2.tld:444/folder/, which doesn't exist.

Since the redirection from "folder" to "folder/" is automatically done, what can I do to fix my problem?

#### Mod-rewrite config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName host2.tld
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}:444%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Please post your config.  At the very least, the mod_rewrite config in question.

Comment: Configuration added.

Comment: So, wait, I'm confused.  Is the problem the addition of the trailing slash, or is the problem the setting of the scheme to `http` on the redirect to port 444?

Comment: Is there any `.htaccess` or another `.conf` file which is included?

Comment: The problem is that when omitting the trailing slash, apache redirect to `http://host2.tld:444/folder/` (instead of https) resulting in a bad request. If I put the trailing slash, everything works fine.

Comment: The config you posted will only apply to requests to `sub.host2.tld` which is not used in your examples. Please post the config for `host2.tld` (will be listed in a ServerName or ServerAlias directive), or if the info you posted (conf/examples) is wrong, please correct it.

Comment: You can also use the RewriteLog directive to debug your rewrite rules. This directive can be used in a virtual host context. Use it with RewriteLogLevel 3 or higher.

Comment: @fuscata It is the same, I put `sub.` by mistake when typing it there.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the L from your rewrite rule.  That option indicates that rule is the 'last' rule and no further rewriting will occur.

When you go to `http://host2.tld/folder` it rewrites the uri to add the slash, but doesn't process any further.

You may also want/need to add a condition to the rewrite in order to prevent a loop on every request.